# How do I transfer text from a text file to a list box splitting on a certain character?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file, text, listbox

I have a text file that contains data as follows:

```
[Section A]
55555
66666
77777 (all on separate lines)

[Section B]
AAAAA
BBBBB (each on a separate line)
```

I just want to know how I can read this data in, and place the data in `[Section A]` only into `listboxA` and the data in `[Section B]` into `listboxB`.

Comment: This question is a perfect example of how beginners can't solve their problems because they try to solve multiple problems at the same time. Reading text from a file, splitting text on a delimiter and populating a `ListBox` are all independent actions and you should treat them as such. Research each separately, implement each separately and then combine your partial solutions to create a total solution. Divide and conquer is problem-solving 101, not just for programming. Also, spend some time in the Help Center and learn how to write a proper question for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code depends on the pattern being exactly as depicted in your question. I placed the text file in the bin\Debug folder for testing but you will need the full path if located elsewhere.

The first `Do` loop looks for the empty line between Section A and Section B. The final `Do` loop stops when it reaches the end of the lines array.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Sections.txt")
    Dim index = 0
    If lines(0) = "[Section A]" Then
        index = 1
        Do While lines(Index) <> ""
            ListBox1.Items.Add(lines(index))
            index += 1
        Loop
    End If
    index += 1
    If lines(index) = "[Section B]" Then
        index += 1
        Do Until index = lines.Length
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(index))
            index += 1
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mary that works fine.  Now if I wanted to amend the [Section B] entry, but not touch the section A entry, how would I then write this to the file to only update that one section?  I have been trying to use File.WriteAllText but the whole file is being overwritten each time.

Comment: @Mark1024 That is a new question. Ask a new question on editing a text file. Writing to a text file beginning at a certain line.

Answer (score 0):

> **Regex**

---

It can be an easy task through the [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions). Consider the following example:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
'...

Private Sub TheCaller()
    Dim path = "TheFullPathOfTheTextFile"
    Dim patt = "(\[.*\]\s)([A-Za-z0-9\s\,.\-_!@#$%^&*()=+;:'`~|""?<>\/\\]+)"
    Dim matches = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(path),
                        patt, RegexOptions.Multiline).Cast(Of Match)

    If matches.Count = 2 Then
        ListBoxA.Items.AddRange(
            matches.First().Groups(2).Value.
            Split({ControlChars.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            )
        ListBoxB.Items.AddRange(
            matches.Last().Groups(2).Value.
            Split({ControlChars.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            )
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that, `Groups(1)` of each match captures the `[Section X]` part where `X` either `A` or `B` in your example. The `Groups(2)` captures the `data` of the section as string. Split this string on `vbCrLf` which is `ControlChars.NewLine` to get strings arrays so you can insert them into your ListBoxes.

See the online Regex test [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/25).

---

> **Extension Methods**

---

Alternatively, you can relay on the extensions to get the data of both sections through the [TakeWhile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netcore-3.1) and [SkipWhile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=netcore-3.1) methods:

```vb
Private Sub TheCaller()
    ListBoxA.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBoxB.DataSource = Nothing

    Dim allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path)

    ListBoxA.DataSource = allLines.Skip(1).
        TakeWhile(Function(x) x <> "[Section B]").
        Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList

    ListBoxB.DataSource = allLines.SkipWhile(Function(x) x <> "[Section B]").
        Skip(1).Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList
End Sub
```

<sup>**Note:** Binding the ListBoxes to data sources as an alternative of adding the items manually.</sup>

The [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netcore-3.1) method in both queries is to skip the `[Section x]` line.

---

> **Loop**

---

A simple `For..Each` loop without using any extensions:

```vb
Private Sub TheCaller()
    Dim listBox = ListBoxA

    For Each line In File.ReadAllLines(path)
        If line = "[Section B]" Then
            listBox = ListBoxB
            Continue For
        ElseIf line = "[Section A]" Then
            Continue For
        End If

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) Then
            listBox.Items.Add(line)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the RegEx one as well, some good methods in there.

Comment: @Mark1024 Most welcome buddy. Just wanted to show you different ways to solve the problem in addition to Mary's answer. Might be useful.